# 3 classes A open C and B open C which one trigged C android

Tags: android

android 
I have 3 classes,the first and the second class goes to the third class by startactivityforresult and each one do a different treatment i want to know how from the third class i know which class(the first or the second) opened  the third class 
in other word A=>C and B=>C which one open C 
sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 1):

Are you using startActivityForResult when launching the activity?
Take a look at [getCallingActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29). If you're just starting the other activity with a basic intent, you'll have to put extras and get extras to identify the class that invoked activity C.

Answer (score 0):

Put a class identifier in the `Intent` payload that starts the `Activity`.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, C.class);
myIntent.putExtra("activityThatStartedMe", getClass().getName());
```

In your other `Activity`, you should be able to pull it out by the key "activityThatStartedMe".

```
String activityName = intent.getExtras().getString("activityThatStartedMe");
```

Answer (score 0):

before saying start ACtivity for result say..

```
intent.put("className" , "A"); // A is your class name
```

and in other class say.

```
getIntent.getExtra("className");
```